# How to understand that affine cone of Grassmannian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311148.pdf), 
On page 5, it is said that the affine cone of a Grassmannian $Gr(k,n)$ is the affine subvariety of decomposable $k$-forms in $\Lambda^k \mathbb{C}^n$. I am trying to understand this. By definition, the affine cone of $Gr(k,n)$ is $\{0\} \cup \pi^{-1}(Gr(k,n))$, where $\pi$ is the canonical projection from the affine space whose dimension is greater than $Gr(k,n)$ by 1 to $Gr(k,n)$. Why the affine cone of $Gr(k,n)$ is the affine subvariety of decomposable $k$-forms in $\Lambda^k \mathbb{C}^n$? Thank you very much.

Comment: In general, the affine cone of a projective variety $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is the subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ defined by the same ideal as $X$. Now, a Grassmannian $G(k,n)$ has a Plucker embedding into $\mathbb{P}(\wedge^k \mathbb{C}^n)$. This embedding can be described as sending a choice of basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ with $w_i \in \mathbb{C}^n$ of a $k$-plane to the (line spanned by) the decomposable form $w_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge w_k$. So the image of the Plucker embedding is exactly the decomposable $k$-forms.